# Schema for group module

Tags: 8, database, group

I have installed [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/rdfui) module and I assume that this works not only in the regular content type but also in the group module. I was expecting that after enabling the module there is an option to map my group type fields in the manage fields section but none even in the edit setting of the group type.

See RDF Mappings in the Basic Page content type:
[image]

**Notice this from the module:**

> Features
>
> RDF UI Map Content Types to Schema.org Types. Map Fields to Schema.org
>   properties.

Does the group module supports schema integration? If yes, is there any documentation provided?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to explain what kind of integration you're looking for.

Comment: Added details of my current case.

Answer (score 0):

The [RDF UI](https://drupal.org/project/rdfui) module only provides the 'RDF Mapping' local task for nodes at the moment (so not Group entities). See the `if` statement in this snippet from `Drupal\rdfui\Plugin\Derivative\RdfUiLocalTask::getDerivativeDefinitions()`:

```
foreach ($this->entityManager->getDefinitions() as $entity_type_id => $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->get('field_ui_base_route') && $entity_type_id === "node") {

    $this->derivatives["overview_$entity_type_id"] = array(
      'route_name' => "entity.$entity_type_id.field_ui_fields",
      'title' => $this->t('Fields'),
      'parent_id' => "field_ui.fields:overview_$entity_type_id",
    );

    $this->derivatives["rdf_$entity_type_id"] = array(
      'route_name' => "entity.$entity_type_id.rdf_ui_fields",
      'weight' => 2,
      'title' => $this->t('RDF Mappings'),
      'parent_id' => "field_ui.fields:overview_$entity_type_id",
    );

  }
}
```